# How to Center Rotate an Overlay Image in a Complex Cloudinary URL Transformation?

Tags: cloudinary

I'm working with a Cloudinary URL to apply multiple transformations to an image, including fetching an overlay image, resizing, adding borders, and rotating the overlay. My goal is to rotate the overlay image around its center, but the rotation appears to be off-centered. I've attempted to adjust various parameters, but due to the complexity of the transformations and the need to maintain the current x_ and y_ values for positioning, I'm facing challenges in achieving the desired center rotation effect.

Here's the Cloudinary URL I'm working with:

https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudname/image/fetch/e_trim:3/h_1800,w_1800,c_pad/bo_200px_solid_white/l_fetch:aHR0cHM6Ly9wcm9tb2h1bnQtc3RvcmVzLXByb2R1Y3Rpb24uczMuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbS9scDJrcGxhd2tpZ3oxdmNrbnN5dDdkMzh1a2E3/c_pad,fl_relative,g_north,a_-4,w_0.12,h_0.12/fl_layer_apply,g_north_west,x_1253,y_1397/https://cdnp.sanmar.com/medias/sys_master/images/images/h68/he7/8869170642974/6223-TwilightBlue-1-BG204twilightbluefront-1200W.jpg

The rotation (a_-4) is applied to the overlay, but it does not seem to rotate around the overlay image's center (Try this URL without the rotation - https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudname/image/fetch/e_trim:3/h_1800,w_1800,c_pad/bo_200px_solid_white/l_fetch:aHR0cHM6Ly9wcm9tb2h1bnQtc3RvcmVzLXByb2R1Y3Rpb24uczMuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbS9scDJrcGxhd2tpZ3oxdmNrbnN5dDdkMzh1a2E3/c_pad,fl_relative,g_north,w_0.12,h_0.12/fl_layer_apply,g_north_west,x_1253,y_1397/https://cdnp.sanmar.com/medias/sys_master/images/images/h68/he7/8869170642974/6223-TwilightBlue-1-BG204twilightbluefront-1200W.jpg).
I need to retain the specific x_ and y_ values for the overlay's positioning relative to the base image.
I'm looking for a solution that allows the overlay to rotate around its center without modifying its positioning values (x_, y_).

Questions:

- Is there a way to adjust the rotation center for the overlay within this URL structure without altering the x_ and y_ positioning values?
- Are there advanced Cloudinary features or transformation expressions that I might not be utilizing correctly to solve this issue?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem, including any examples or documentation references that might be relevant.

Comment: So displacement should help you with this, see https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_use_displacement_maps_to_transform_images, let me know if this helps.